# Docker build ends with error "the command ... returned a non-zero code: 100"

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-build

I am building a Docker image and the `Dockerfile` looks like follow:

```
FROM ubuntu:12.04
MAINTAINER Maintainer Name <my_address@goes.here>

VOLUME ["/var/www"]

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
    apache2 \
    php5 \
    php5-cli \
    libapache2-mod-php5 \
    php5-gd \
    php5-ldap \
    php5-mysql

COPY apache_default /etc/apache2/sites-available/default
COPY run /usr/local/bin/run
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/run
RUN a2enmod rewrite

EXPOSE 80
CMD ["/usr/local/bin/run"]
```

The run file contains the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

PHP_ERROR_REPORTING=${PHP_ERROR_REPORTING:-"E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_NOTICE"}
sed -ri 's/^display_errors\s*=\s*Off/display_errors = On/g' /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
sed -ri 's/^display_errors\s*=\s*Off/display_errors = On/g' /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
sed -ri "s/^error_reporting\s*=.*$//g" /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
sed -ri "s/^error_reporting\s*=.*$//g" /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
echo "error_reporting = $PHP_ERROR_REPORTING" >> /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
echo "error_reporting = $PHP_ERROR_REPORTING" >> /etc/php5/cli/php.ini

source /etc/apache2/envvars && exec /usr/sbin/apache2 -DFOREGROUND
```

I am seeing some errors output to the console when I run the command:

```
docker build -t dev-image .
```

The lines marked with `---` (this is just for show you the lines doesn't mean that the ouput has such symbol) at the end are marked in red in the console:

```
...
Get:69 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main ssl-cert all 1.0.28ubuntu0.1 [12.3 kB]
debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed ---
Fetched 26.7 MB in 48s (550 kB/s)
...
Unpacking ucf (from .../ucf_3.0025+nmu2ubuntu1_all.deb) ...
Moving old data out of the way ---
Selecting previously unselected package ttf-dejavu-core
...
Setting up ucf (3.0025+nmu2ubuntu1) ...
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog ---
debconf: (TERM is not set, so the dialog frontend is not usable.) ---
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline ---
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Readline ---
debconf: (This frontend requires a controlling tty.) ---
debconf: falling back to frontend: Teletype ---
Setting up ttf-dejavu-core (2.33-2ubuntu1) ...
...
Setting up php5-cli (5.3.10-1ubuntu3.24) ...
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog ---
debconf: (TERM is not set, so the dialog frontend is not usable.) ---
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline ---
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Readline ---
debconf: (This frontend requires a controlling tty.) ---
debconf: falling back to frontend: Teletype ---

Creating config file /etc/php5/cli/php.ini with new version ---
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/php5 to provide /usr/bin/php (php) in auto mode.
...
Setting up apache2-mpm-prefork (2.2.22-1ubuntu1.11) ...
invoke-rc.d: policy-rc.d denied execution of start. ---
Setting up apache2 (2.2.22-1ubuntu1.11) ...
...
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place

Errors were encountered while processing:
 ssl-cert
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update &&     apt-get install -y     apache2     php5     php5-cli     libapache2-mod-php5     php5-gd     php5-ldap     php5-mysql' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

Why? What I am not notice here? Did I miss something?

I am running Docker 1.10.3 in Fedora 24:

```
$ docker -v
Docker version 1.10.3, build a612434/1.10.3
```

**UPDATE**

After I had remove all the images & containers and run a clean build using `--no-cache` I can see this error now:

```
Setting up ssl-cert (1.0.28ubuntu0.1) ...
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (TERM is not set, so the dialog frontend is not usable.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Readline
debconf: (This frontend requires a controlling tty.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Teletype
groupadd: failure while writing changes to /etc/group
addgroup: `/usr/sbin/groupadd -g 102 ssl-cert' returned error code 10. Exiting.
dpkg: error processing ssl-cert (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
```

Which makes sense with the error, the question is why?

Comment: Any lines on apt-utils in your output? First guess is you're getting a bad package mirror.

Comment: @BMitch what do you mean with `Any lines on apt-utils in your output?` ? And I've tried ten times by now couldn't be possible that all the tries I get a bad package mirror and if so any way to force it so I can get packages from an specific mirror?

Comment: @BMitch the mirror seems to be `http://archive.ubuntu.com` since is the URL I am seeing is hit on through the installation process

Comment: Failure writing to /etc/group is curious, are you out of disk space?

Comment: Note that you can clean up a lot of your warnings by adding `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install ...` to your apt-get install line.

Comment: @BMitch no, I have a lot of space around 80GB in the `/` partition

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123899/discussion-between-bmitch-and-reynierpm).

Comment: @BMitch apparently something is wrong with that specific Ubuntu image since I have changed to `ubuntu:14.04.5` and everything went fine. I have not made any changes to the docker directories as you suggested me over the chat and did nothing else just changed the FROM and adjust the Dockerfile to install PHP 5.6.x instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've stepped through your Dockerfile manually using `docker run -it ubuntu:12.04` and going through the steps (which is a good tip, by the way, when you're putting together a complex image).

The `apt-get` commands all worked fine for me. Your error is about the `ssl-cert` install, so your build failed on the first `RUN` instruction and the rest of the Dockerfile won't have been processed.

Possibly a temporary issue when you were building? Have you tried again or on a different host?

Comment: I've tried three times by now always with same result. You mention that the error happen when the first `RUN` is being executed, I have added this part to the OP, is something wrong there?

Comment: No, I don't think there's anything wrong with the Dockerfile - I've just tried building your exact Dockerfile & run script in a sandboxed Docker environment on Katacoda.com and it built fine. Maybe clear your cache with `docker rmi ubuntu:12.04` and try again?

Comment: Grrrrrrrrrr already tried that, same error, yours runs fine? What's your Docker version? Which OS?

Comment: Thanks Elton, take a look to the latest comment on OP.